# Writing into a local excel workbook form Dialogflow webhook

Tags: node.js, excel, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

As part of chat bot operation, I want to write out conversation entity values to an excel sheet. More like a logger.

And I am using it as a separate function inside the webhook fullfillment code (nodeJS) using excel4node.

Wanted to know if and how this write operation can be done to an Excel workbook saved on my local machine.

As per my understanding, a write workbook operation in fullfillment will be saving the Excel workbook on Google`s Dialogflow server and not local directory..

Has any one encountered a similar situation and has a solution for this?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

It will not save it on Dialogflow's server - it will save it wherever the webhook runs. If you are using Dialogflows Built In editor, then it will save it to a disk used by Firebase Cloud Functions, and will likely not be available to you.

But you can run the webhook on any machine that has:

1. A public IP address.
2. A valid HTTPS server using a non-self-signed certificate.

So if you have a machine that meets this criteria where you have access to the local disk so you can access the Excel file that is generated - you can do this.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Let me work this up and confirm.